# Issue w/ mapping array of props object into Data table component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to create a data table using react. I am able to properly display the data from the object I am passing as props within the table. However, all of the data is displayed in the first column of the table, rather than spread across all columns.

The prop I am passing in App.js is the following:

```js
const obj = [
  {
    date: "2019-04-17",
    spend: 100,
    preloads: 111.43,
    installs: 100
  },
  {
    date: "2019-04-16",
    spend: 200,
    preloads: 911.43,
    installs: 200
  },
  {
    date: "2019-04-15",
    spend: 300,
    preloads: 9211.43,
    installs: 300
  }
];
```

and I am rendering within App.js with:

```
<MetricsTable data={obj}/>
```

My MetricsTable.js component file is the following:

```
import React from "react";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";

class TableRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const row =
      this.props.data &&
      data.map(data => (
        <tr>
          <td>{data.date}</td>
          <td>{data.spend}</td>
          <td>{data.preloads}</td>
          <td>{data.installs}</td>
        </tr>
      ));
    return <div>{row}</div>;
  }
}

class MetricsTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Spend ($)</th>
              <th>Preloads</th>
              <th>Installs</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <TableRow data={this.props.data && this.props.data} />
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MetricsTable;
```

However, when I run this code this is how the data comes out:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can spread the data across the column headers?

Comment: Look at the emitted markup, that's **not** a valid table.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe - do you mind explaining which section of the code isn't valid? I'm using react-bootstrap Table.

Comment: The library, or even use of React, isn't the problem; this would happen with a vanilla `table` element too. Compare your output to the examples at e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: Try this, change data to item in your map function, this.props.data((item) => etc. Possibly this is causing the issue.

Comment: @vitomadio how would renaming that loop variable change anything?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've updated the code on the post using the example you sent - using <table>, <thead>, <tr>, etc element; however, I'm still running into the same issues...

Comment: So what's the actual markup now? You still have a span, which is **not** part of the table element hierarchy.

Comment: Because you have destrucred data so de variable data inside map func is this.props.data  it is an array not an object

Comment: ...nor is a div.

Comment: @vitomadio the data *is* being displayed, just in the wrong layout, so that part's clearly working.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've figured it out, I just need to be returning `row` not `<div>{row}</div>` - I don't exactly understand the fundamentals behind this. <div> is just used to create divisions and doesn't actually markup anything (i think?). Is the issue more related to the usage of {}?

Comment: Div *has* meaning in the markup, as your example clearly demonstrates. The obvious fix would be to move the tbody into your component, so it's only returning a single thing and still is valid markup.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a functional component instead for `TableRow`. The issue was incorrect markup, as each `<tr>` was being enclosed in a `<span>`.

```
export default function TableRow(props) {
  console.log(props);
  const { data } = props;
  return obj.map(data => (
    <tr>
      <td>{data.date}</td>
      <td>{data.spend}</td>
      <td>{data.preloads}</td>
      <td>{data.installs}</td>
    </tr>
  ));
}
```